# what can make the contianer ip change on docker swarm mode

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-container

- I have a application which save IP of docker service to connect another service;
- The IP of docker service which the app to connect changed;
- the app can't conncet the dockker service;
- I want to kown what happead can make the IP of docker service change;
- I kown one is docker service container restart,but my docker container not restart,and my docker service IP changed,my application can't find the docker service using old IP;
- there do not have any error or warning in docked logs;
- who kown another reason can make the docker service's IP change;

Comment: Please add examples to your question, it's not clear by itself: show what you do, what change, what is the expected result and what is the actual result. Add a description of your deployment (docker-compose file if any)